# Datagridview built from access database - combobox

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, combobox

I fount this tutorial to help me display a combobox in a datagridview that is coming from a database. 
I need to use SQL DATA SOURCE I usually code everything so I am not used working with it. If I have 10 combobox to display, do I need to create a datasource for each one of them?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178294.aspx

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're reuse same data source for multiple controls then you get same set of data for all the combo boxes. You can set value members and display members of combo's only from single select statement. If it's ok with your requirements then you can reuse same data source.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Product ID";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Product Name";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Product Price";

            string[] row = new string[] { "1", "Product 1", "1000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "2", "Product 2", "2000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "3", "Product 3", "3000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "4", "Product 4", "4000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            cmb.HeaderText = "Select Data";
            cmb.Name = "cmb";
            cmb.MaxDropDownItems = 4;
            cmb.Items.Add("True");
            cmb.Items.Add("False");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb);

        }
    }
}
```

Also, here is an efficient way to load a DataGridView from Access.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=your .mdb file;";
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Authors";
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
            OleDbDataAdapter dataadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            connection.Open();
            dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Authors_table");
            connection.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            dataGridView1.DataMember = "Authors_table";
        }
    }
}
```